# Multiple inputs for shell

Tags: shell, scripting

Got struck while trying to write a shell script which should automatically give input.

While running a script for eg: `adpatch.sh`

It Prompts for Multiple inputs like:

```
Do you currently have files used for installing or upgrading the database
installed in this APPL_TOP [YES] ? need to give input here


Do you currently have Java and HTML files for HTML-based functionality
installed in this APPL_TOP [YES] ? need to give input here


Do you currently have Oracle Applications forms files installed
in this APPL_TOP [YES] ? need to give input here


Do you currently have concurrent program files installed
in this APPL_TOP [YES] ? need to give input here
```

so without using Command Line Arguments, is there any other way of giving the input automatically?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is what you want.  You may need to install it first ("apt-get install expect" from Debian/Ubuntu based Linux distros).

Expect has the advantage of pairing responses with specific questions, instead of just blindly replying with "YES".

From the [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

> In general, Expect is useful for running any program which requires
>   interaction between the program and the user.  All that is necessary
>   is that the interaction can be characterized programmatically.  Expect
>   can also give the user back control (without halting the program being
>   controlled) if desired.  Similarly, the user can return control to the
>   script at any time".

Comment: Good advice although it needs a lot more work than the alternative of redirecting input. There is also "autoexpect" (http://wiki.tcl.tk/1865) that automates the writing of expect scripts! With minor changes you can have a working expect script!